# PyQt5 thread sequencing

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I am having difficulties trying to iterate through each row in a table using PyQt and QThreads in order.  I have simplified the code below (my original code involves threads to perform SQL queries)

The code below creates a button and also a table with three rows and three columns. On pressing the launch button the text is read from the first row in the table and passes it to the thread. In the thread (with simulated delay) the string is reversed and passed back to the main thread.  Next the reversed string is passed back to another thread instance and returns the string back to the original order and updates the table.  The plan is to iterate over each row

My problem is that the my code appears to perform all the reverse string actions on all rows first, and then performs all the string undo actions on all the rows second, and then dumps the update to the table at the end

I was hoping to perform the reverse action on the first row and then the undo action on that same row, before moving on to the next row in the table, whist updating the changes in the table

Here's a view of the results table:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import functools


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(str)
    result = pyqtSignal(object)


class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, string_list):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()  # Create an instance of our signals class.
        self.string_list = string_list

    def run(self):
        for string in self.string_list:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.signals.result.emit(string[::-1])
        self.signals.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Testing ')
        central = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout(central)
        buttonLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)

        button1 = QPushButton('Launch') # Add launch button
        buttonLayout.addWidget(button1)

        tableLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(tableLayout)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.centralWidget()) # Add table
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Test A"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Test B"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 2, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Test C"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 2, QTableWidgetItem(""))

        tableLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.show()

        button1.clicked.connect(self.start_tests) # Trigger start_tests method on button clicked

    def call_worker(self, my_string, fn, row):
        """ Prep worker thread request in main thread"""
        self.my_string = my_string
        self.fn = fn
        self.row = row

        self.thread = QThread(self)
        self.worker = Worker([self.my_string])
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        self.worker.signals.result.connect(functools.partial(self.fn, self.row))
        self.worker.signals.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()
        return self.thread

    def start_tests(self):
        self.launch_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S')
        print(self.launch_time)

        all_rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        all_rows = [i for i in range(0, all_rows)]

        """Iterate through each row in table to perform a couple of actions, by calling a thread to run first to 
        reverse a string, then to pass to another method to undo the reverse in another thread, update the table row
        then proceed to the next row in the table"""
        for row in all_rows:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem('Queued'))
            self.tableWidget.item(row, 1).setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(255, 255, 0))

            self.test_str = (self.tableWidget.item(row, 0)).text()

            # First thread call
            self.call_worker(self.test_str, self.undo_changes, row)

    def undo_changes(self, row, reverse_str):
        self.row = row
        self.reverse_str = reverse_str

        print(f'String reversed to: {self.reverse_str}')

        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.row, 1, QTableWidgetItem('Passed'))
        self.tableWidget.item(self.row, 1).setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(0, 255, 255))

        # Second thread call
        self.call_worker(self.reverse_str, self.add_to_third_column, self.row)


    def add_to_third_column(self, row, orig_string):
        self.row = row
        self.orig_string = orig_string

        print(f'String RETURNED to: {self.orig_string}')
        # update table row
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.row, 2, QTableWidgetItem(self.orig_string))
        self.tableWidget.item(self.row, 2).setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(255, 0, 255))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Here's the printed output I currently get:

```
String reversed to: A tseT
String reversed to: B tseT
String reversed to: C tseT
String RETURNED to: Test A
String RETURNED to: Test B
String RETURNED to: Test C
```

This is what I was hoping to get whilst updating the table after each row:

```
String reversed to: A tseT    
String RETURNED to: Test A    #Then update table
String reversed to: B tseT
String RETURNED to: Test B    #Then update table
String reversed to: C tseT   
String RETURNED to: Test C    #Then update table
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Note that `Worker` already inherits from QObject, there's no need for a separate object for the signals. Also, if you call `wait` on a thread you are practically invalidating the point of a thread, as the function won't return until the thread has finished (hence your result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has the following problems:

- You should not use quit() immediately you execute the start() since that method will block the eventloop until the thread ends and that is not expected in a GUI since it will freeze.
- Don't abuse attributes, use `self.foo` when really necessary, not everything has to be an attribute.
- It is not necessary to create a WorkerSignals since the Worker is a QObject that can have signals, this technique is used in QRunnables that cannot have their own signals.
- If you want the threads to run in queue then you must implement the logic that when one task finishes the other starts, the for-loop does not work in this case. In Qt you must use events to perform actions.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys
import time
from functools import partial

from datetime import datetime

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QTableWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QHBoxLayout,
)


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(str)
    result = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, string_list):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.string_list = string_list

    def run(self):
        for string in self.string_list:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.result.emit(string[::-1])
        self.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Testing ")
        central = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout(central)
        buttonLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)

        button1 = QPushButton("Launch")  # Add launch button
        buttonLayout.addWidget(button1)

        tableLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(tableLayout)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.centralWidget())  # Add table
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Test A"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Test B"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 2, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Test C"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 2, QTableWidgetItem(""))

        tableLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

        button1.clicked.connect(self.start_tests)

    def call_worker(self, my_string, fn, row):
        """Prep worker thread request in main thread"""

        thread = QThread(self)
        worker = Worker([my_string])
        worker.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.worker = worker

        thread.started.connect(worker.run)
        worker.result.connect(partial(fn, row))
        worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
        worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
        thread.finished.connect(thread.deleteLater)

        thread.start()

    def start_tests(self):
        launch_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S")
        print(launch_time)

        all_rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        all_rows = [i for i in range(0, all_rows)]

        for row in all_rows:
            item = QTableWidgetItem("Queued")
            item.setBackground(QColor.fromRgb(255, 255, 0))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, item)

        self.start_reversed(0)

    def start_reversed(self, row):
        test_str = self.tableWidget.item(row, 0).text()
        self.call_worker(test_str, self.start_undo, row)

    def start_undo(self, row, reverse_str):
        print(f"String reversed to: {reverse_str}")

        item1 = self.tableWidget.item(row, 1)
        item1.setText("Passed")
        item1.setBackground(QColor.fromRgb(0, 255, 255))
        self.call_worker(reverse_str, self.finished_undo, row)

    def finished_undo(self, row, orig_string):
        item0 = self.tableWidget.item(row, 0)
        item0.setText(orig_string)
        print(f"String RETURNED to: {orig_string}")

        item = QTableWidgetItem(orig_string)
        item.setBackground(QColor.fromRgb(255, 0, 255))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, item)

        row += 1
        if row < self.tableWidget.rowCount():
            self.start_reversed(row)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Output:

```
String reversed to: A tseT
String RETURNED to: Test A
String reversed to: B tseT
String RETURNED to: Test B
String reversed to: C tseT
String RETURNED to: Test C
```

Comment: Thank you so much @eyllanesc, it's working correctly as you mentioned.  The QRunnables signals were a left over from when I tried the QRunnables technique, I swapped to QThread to see if that fixed my initial problem.  Out of interest, could I get the same behaviour if I switched back to the QRunnables technique and reinstated the worker signals?  I guess the key is passing the 'row' number between methods